# How to rename a file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, dir

Here's my .rb file:

```
puts "Renaming files..."

folder_path = "/home/papuccino1/Desktop/Test"
Dir.glob(folder_path + "/*").sort.each do |f|
    filename = File.basename(f, File.extname(f))
    File.rename(f, filename.capitalize + File.extname(f))
end

puts "Renaming complete."
```

The files are moved from their initial directory to where the .rb file is located. I'd like to rename the files on the spot, without moving them.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: In what way are they moved and not just renamed? Are they physically moved in the memory, you mean? What makes you believe that? Please elaborate why the current code is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

What about simply:

```
File.rename(f, folder_path + "/" + filename.capitalize + File.extname(f))
```

Answer (score 29):

Doesn't the folder_path have to be part of the filename?

```
puts "Renaming files..."

folder_path = "/home/papuccino1/Desktop/Test/"
Dir.glob(folder_path + "*").sort.each do |f|
  filename = File.basename(f, File.extname(f))
  File.rename(f, folder_path + filename.capitalize + File.extname(f))
end

puts "Renaming complete."
```

edit: it appears Mat is giving the same answer as I, only in a slightly different way.

Comment: Yeah - but your answer explains why - which is always good :)

Answer (score 23):

If you're running in the same location as the file you want to change

```
File.rename("test.txt", "hope.txt")
```

Though honestly, I sometimes I don't see the point in using ruby at all...no need probably so long as your filenames are simply interpreted in the shell:

```
`mv test.txt hope.txt`
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I'd love to see some explanation of how this works.

Comment: Well, @superluminary, 6 years later, this works because the present working directory (`Dir.pwd` in irb or `pwd` in the shell) is the same as the files in the question. To determine if said files are in your directory, use `Dir.glob("*")` in irb or `ls` in shell. If your file is there, this stuff should work...

Comment: @User16119012 back in 2013, were you running Windows?

Comment: @User16119012 I was not --- was and still am running OSX

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a linux file system you could try `mv #{filename} newname`

You can also use File.rename(old,new)

Comment: I'd rather not use Terminal commands and just use Ruby. This script is meant to run on Windows and Linux. Just a little helper script I'm writing to learn about Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this pattern unless you are ready to put proper quoting around filenames:

```
`mv test.txt hope.txt`
```

Indeed, suppose instead of "hope.txt" you have a file called "foo the bar.txt", the result will not be what you expect.

Comment: Link to method: https://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/mv