# Renaming Script in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write my first Ruby script that will rename files in a specific folder. I am basing my script off of this response : [How to rename a file in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530479/how-to-rename-a-file-in-ruby). However, I need help elaborating on some things. Here is the code from the above link that I currently have written out.

```
puts "Renaming files..."

folder_path = "/Desktop/untitled/"

Dir.glob( folder_path + "*" ).sort.each do |f|
  filename = File.basename(f, File.extname(f))
  File.rename( f, folder_path + filename.capitalize + File.extname(f))
end

puts "Renaming complete."
```

With this example, I understand that the script is simply capitalizing the name of the original file. But what do I do if I want to insert a segment in the name of the file. Say for example I have:
    "This is my name."

written out. What would I do if I just want to focus on the "my name" portion, and change it into something that would state:

```
"This is my (first) name."
```

Also, what if I wanted to remove a space:

```
"This is myfirstname."
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: This has nothing to do with files. These are basic string manipulations.

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm really new to Ruby. Or any programming for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to achieve replacing portion of the filename with something else, you should use a `sub` or `gsub` function of the `String` class:

`filename = File.basename(f, File.extname(f))`

Now in filename you have stored a `String` representing a current file's name. You can check it using `instance_of?` function of an `Object` class, just if you're curious:

```
filename.instance_of?(String)
# -> true
```

What you should do is to use `gsub` method to replace all occurencies of given string, or `sub` to replace only first of it. [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) you can find detailed information of using these functions.

I suppose in your case this should do the trick:

```
filename.gsub('my name', 'my (first) name')
# 2nd question:
filename.gsub("my first name", "myfirstname")
```

Also, regular expressions are allowed in `sub` and `gsub` methods. You should give it a try if you want to write more complex patterns, for example strip all numbers from file.

Comment: for the 2nd question, your changing the whole string to be unspaced. But what would I do if I only wanted to unspace part of the string? I understand lstrip and rstrip deal with the end and beginning, but im not sure how to edit the middle. Here is an example: "My first name is Bob" to "My firstname is Bob". So I would think of doing the same for .gsub "first name", "firstname", but what if i wanted to change the string first to f first and then proceed? Likeso: "My first name is Bob" to "My fname is Bob"

Comment: "My first name is Bob".gsub('first', 'f') => My f name is Bob. But I want to remove that space between f and name.

Comment: `"My first name is Bob".gsub('first name', 'fname')
"My fname is Bob"` or if the string is in `filename`, another alternate is `firstname['first name'] = 'fname'`.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to create strings with variables in Ruby is:

```
first = "Eugene"
filename = "This is my #{first} name"
```

filename is equal to "This is my Eugene name"

so with the file portions you asked about:

```
"This is my #{folder_path}#{filename.gsub!(' ', '').capitalize}#{File.extname(f)}"
```

Removing spaces can be done with gsub 
(check out string class documentation http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html):

```
filename.gsub(' ', '')
```

You can also use the File classes join method to concatenate strings into a path and avoid cross platform issues with slashes ('/' vs '\')
For more see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-join