# A shell script to change filenames

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a large number of image files in my project but all of them have spaces in them which was causing issues on github. I need to change them all using rails console and add '-' instead of a spaces.
I know it is possible but can't get it. Used this to move and change a single filename:

`cd app/assets/images && mv avatar.png avatar123.png`

Comment: Define "can't get it". What did you try already? The types of files isn't relevant. Your example doesn't encapsulate the problem, btw. Renaming a file is a one-liner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530479/how-to-rename-a-file-in-ruby. Changing directories and iterating over files is similarly well-documented in both the Ruby docs and elsewhere. Please be specific with the problem(s) you're having.

Comment: @DaveNewton I found the answer after 2 hours search and it works perfectly but haven't figured out how it does work, yet.

Comment: Everything in your answer has `man` docs. But this has nothing to do with the Rails console--your example and your answer is a shell script.

Comment: @DaveNewton I totally understand what you meant back then but I was very new to the concept. Sorry for making you want to hit a wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to solve the issue with this 2nd script on this page:
[Source](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6877/replace-spaces-in-a-filename-with-hyphens)

My current script goes like this and it worked 100% :
`cd app/assets/images && for f in * ; do mv "$f" $( echo $f | tr ' ' '-' ) ; done`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Rails console. This is a shell script.